# php preg_match_all get block of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need to septate out some paragraph from my file, it's start with some string and end with special character like !
I am using preg_match_all to get the result, please find below link and select preg_match_all
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/m5C

and I want output like

```
0=> array(
    0=>     ip vrf Access-Mgmt
        rd 65000:3298
        route-target export 65000:4585
        route-target export 65000:4717
        route-target import 65000:4585
        route-target import 65000:2659
)
```

Comment: whats the problem you've encountered?

Comment: You need just first paragraph, right? Problem is that '!' exists at the end of every other paragraph, too...so, you need to match only first occurence?

Comment: yes  sinisake , You are right

Comment: $result=explode('!',$str);echo $result[0];?

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/m5G You could make your `.*?` non  greedy.

Comment: Thanks lot, You save my day. phpliveregex.com/p/m5G this working

Comment: @infi please review the answers (that's where answers are meant to be posted).  My answer used best practices.  If you don't understand, please ask me to explain.  Do you know how to accept an answer?  You even earn points for doing so.

Comment: Here we see yet another case of **Premature Abandonment**  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230676/hey-you-yeah-you-post-your-answers-as-answers-not-comments/296481#296481  Everyone loses, including Stackoverflow.  Now @infi is going to use a pattern that is less efficient than one posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for regex in this specific case because you want the first portion the precedes the first `!`.  `strstr()` does this well.  `explode('!',$string,2)[0]` will work but it is a less direct hack, because it generates an array before extracting the desired string from the first element.

Code:

```
echo trim(strstr($string,'!',true));
```

Output:

```
ip vrf Access-Mgmt
 rd 65000:3298
 route-target export 65000:4585
 route-target export 65000:4717
 route-target import 65000:4585
 route-target import 65000:2659
```

Or if you are not targeting the first block of text, and rather want the `Access-Mgmt` block, you can use `preg_match()` with this pattern: `/ip vrf Access-Mgmt[^!]+/` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wTiZ3f/1) or trim the trailing newline character with `/ip vrf Access-Mgmt[^!]+(?=\R)/`.

Here is what these calls can look like:

```
var_export(preg_match('/ip vrf Access-Mgmt[^!]+/',$string,$out)?$out[0]:'fail');
// or
var_export(preg_match('/ip vrf Access-Mgmt[^!]+(?=\R)/',$string,$out)?$out[0]:'fail');
// or
var_export(preg_match('/ip vrf Access-Mgmt[^!]+/',$string,$out)?trim($out[0]):'fail');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can checkout the preg_match_all at http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/m5H

What I've done is splitted the string with the condition **([^!]*)!** and replacement **$0**

**Explanation:**

```
( - start capture group
  [ - start capture group
    ^! - match anything but ! symbol
  ] - start capture group
  * - match 0 or more occurances
) - start capture group
! - followed by ! symbol

$0 - First capture group
```

Let me know if this solves your use case.

**Output:**

```
1   =>  Array(
    0   =>  Array(
        ip vrf Access-Mgmt
         rd 65000:3298
         route-target export 65000:4585
         route-target export 65000:4717
         route-target import 65000:4585
         route-target import 65000:2659
    ),
    1   =>  Array(
        ip vrf Atheeb-VoIP
         rd 65000:4592
         import map Atheeb-VoIP_Imp
         route-target export 65000:6277
         route-target import 65000:6275
         route-target import 65000:6276
         route-target import 65000:6277
    ),
    2   =>  Array(
        ip vrf CISCO
         rd 65000:1
         route-target export 65000:1
         route-target import 65000:1
    ),
    3   =>  Array(
        ip vrf EBU-Modem-DHCP
         rd 10:10
         route-target export 65000:6475
         route-target import 65000:6476
    ),
    4   =>  Array(
        ip vrf ER-DCN
         rd 65000:3719
         route-target export 65000:5241
         route-target import 65000:5241
         route-target import 65000:5242
    ),
    5   =>  Array(
        ip vrf ER-LTE-Media-Signalling
         rd 65000:3723
         route-target export 65000:5245
         route-target import 65000:5245
         route-target import 65000:3507
         route-target import 65000:3511
         route-target import 65000:5535
    ),
    6   =>  Array(
        ip vrf ER-LTE-OAM
         rd 65000:3724
         route-target export 65000:5247
         route-target import 65000:5247
    ),
)
```

Comment: That is one horrifically bloated output array!  If the OP is merely looking for the first substring that is delimited by `!` then regex is a poor choice.

Comment: @mickmackusa The above does not look only for the first substrring, It rather splits the entire string into parts of the output delimited by `!`.

Comment: That is not what the OP wants. and if you are merely going to split on `!` that is what `explode()` is for.  You may read my answer for information on this.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I understand. Thank you for pointing that out.